# How can I execute a comand if condition is true (SQL)

Tags: mysql

I want to compare 2 dates and if there´s a difference bigger than 2 days I want to update the field "data_fecho" from the table.

Here's an example from the table

| id | message | lastupdate | data_fecho |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello | 2021-12-20 15:20:51 | NULL |

```
SELECT id,message,DATEDIFF(NOW(), lastupdate) AS dif FROM tickets;
```

Above I can get the difference between the dates but I can´t update it, doesn´t recognize dif

```
IF (dif > 2)
BEGIN
    UPDATE tickets set data_fecho=NOW()
END
```

Comment: 'doesn´t recognize dif' - true the scope of dif is only within the select . Also 'MySQL supports the IF, CASE, ITERATE, LEAVE LOOP, WHILE, and REPEAT constructs for flow control within stored programs.' and the published if syntax is wrong anyway see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-statements.html.  You might also want to read up select INTO. But given your question an update...set seems appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `where` clause to your `update` statement:

```sql
UPDATE tickets
SET    data_fecho = NOW()
WHERE  DATEDIFF(NOW(), lastupdate) > 2
```